# issue of Generate a Direct Line token

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

When I try to get the direct line Token according to the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#generate-token).

The Error shown in Postman.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Missing token or secret"
  }
}
```

Here with my query

> https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate?Authorization=Bearer
>   EWXpigVssN0.4b2ePfz9L_E3mMM37be6yBGXdgI2GUul7Pm8aRNcUeg&content-Type=application/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending a GET request but what you need to do is send a **POST** request with the **Authorization** set to a **Bearer Token**

Using [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) you can do this like below:

[image]