# Azure Bot Framework - Direct Line integration doesn't display introductory message until user types something

Tags: azure, botframework

I've deployed an Azure bot and now I'm trying to make it available for testing.

I've embedded the bot into a separate Azure web app (inside an html page) following instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) but the introductory message doesn't display until you type something.

So to test my testers will have to enter "go" (or similar) to start testing the bot.

Testing localhost using the emulator is OK.

Testing via the Azure portal is also OK (but my testers won't have access to the Azure portal).

Comment: Using WebChat or directline, the bot's ConversationUpdate is sent when the conversation is created and the user's ConversationUpdate is sent when they first send a message. You will need to send a back channel welcome event to the bot when the DirectLine connection is established and send a [welcome message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) from the onEventAsync handler instead of onMembersAdded.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Send welcome Event Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) showing how to implement that feature in WebChat

Comment: You need to generate a token, check out my answer here showing how to do so using postman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349561/issue-of-generate-a-direct-line-token/59353432#59353432

Answer (score 0):

In your Bot file, add the following code :

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var member in membersAdded)
                {
                    if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        var Userid=turnContext.Activity.From.Name;
                        UserProfile userProfile = await _botStateService.UserProfileAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());
                        userProfile.name = Userid;
                        await _botStateService.UserProfileAccessors.SetAsync(turnContext, userProfile);
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($" Hi, bot here "), cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
```